# Merge a number to Object's name

Tags: c++, object

I am trying to do something like this:

```
int i;
Object a + to_string(i);
```

In order to create Objects with names a1,a2,a3...

Is it possible?

Comment: For a name?  You would need to use the preprocessor:  #define MYNAME(x)  a##i

Comment: Sounds like you want an array or (better) a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use:

```
int;
Object a + to_string(i);
```

Perhaps using a `std::map` is what you are looking for.

```
std::map<std::string, Object> theMap;
theMap[std::string("a") + to_string(i)] = Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is an array, but if you want the "safe" version that respects any input integer, you'd write this:

```
std::map<int,Object> a;
int i = /*...*/;
a[i].methodName();
```

If you want variable names defined dynamically at runtime, that's impossible, as variable names only exist until the compile stage.